# Multiple users on the same table

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I'm building a database
where users will access the same table but they cannot edit each others records.
I'will be using views+insert/update/delete stored procedures from my .NET application.

What's the best way to achieve safe acess to tables?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're building a sort of a multi-tenant application.  For my 10 cents it's better to handle this authorization within your application code.  There's a couple of MSDN artlcles at the link below about architecture for these sort of systems:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

Comment: Even if users have direct database access?

Comment: @gbn - in that case, then obviously not, but if you are controlling all access through your application, then you should be handle it.

Comment: Excellent article! (it's a part of series definately worth reading on this matter)

Answer (score 0):

You can change their security options and disable access to the base tables. You can then do all of your IO through either stored procedures or views.

For example you make a view for company A and another for company B, company A only has rights to see their view and so on.

Comment: Yes, but with more than 1000 users/tenants that seems like an overkill with so much views?

Comment: That would be a lot of views! How about managing the IO through stored procedures that are passed a tenant_ID to restrict their output. You could also look at table valued functions again with the tenant_ID as a parameter